# Intalling timbral_models on Raspeberry Pi 3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have been trying to install `timbral_model` on my Raspberry Pi (`pip3 install timbral_models`) without avail. I can't figure out the errors. The following screenshot provides a better overview.

[image: snapshot]

I would be grateful to anyone for assistance.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not image.

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE: FAILING BUILDING WHEEL FOR SCIKIT-LEARN;  FAILING BUILDING WHEEL FOR LLvmlite; Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip--build/

Answer (score 1):

You might have to install the offending dependencies manually. From the screenshots that you have shared I see that Cython, sklearn and llvmlite are causing the issues. you can install these dependencies by running :

```
pip install sklearn
pip install llvmlite
pip install Cython
```

As I cannot see the entire error message, I can only suggest these fixes. You might also have to manually install any other offending packages.